# Edit VS Code editor.wordSeparator settings, when I delete an entire word, stops after the first capital ( ex. capLocks ---> cap)

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I customize the **editor.wordSeparators** setting in VS code so that when I type ctrl+backspace which deletes for me everything up until a word separator such as space . , etc it will stop past the first capital letter IF a lowercase letter is before it.

helloThere would become hello instead of the entire helloThere being deleted on ctrl+ backspace.

Is it possible to add this into the json settings in VS code?

This is what the setting currently looks like-

"editor.wordSeparators": "`~!@#$%^&*()-=+[{]}\|;:'",.<>/?_"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can add what is basically a regex to the wordSeparators list.  But you can use the command `deleteWordPartLeft` to do what you want.  Make this keybinding (in keybindings.json or find the command in the Keyboard Shortcuts and add the keybinding there):

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+backspace",
  "command": "deleteWordPartLeft"
},
```